# How do I stop Google Sheets from opening new tabs?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have two completely separate spreadsheet files.  In Spreadsheet A, there is a cell with a link to open Spreadsheet B, and vice versa.  When I click on the link, the other Spreadsheet opens up just fine.  However, it opens up in a new tab.  Is there a way to make it open in the same window that I'm working in?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a single spreadsheet with two sheets, and you want to add a link in a cell in Sheet A that switches the active view to Sheet B.

I believe the [`HYPERLINK` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) will solve your problem. The `url` you enter as first parameter to this function should be of the form `"#gid=<sheet id>"` where `<sheet id>` is the [sheet id](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id) for Sheet B.

You can find the gid for Sheet B by switching to the sheet in the browser window, and look for the `gid=` term at the end of the URL. All Google Sheet URLs take the form `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheetId>/edit#gid=<sheetId>`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used the wrong terminology.  I meant to say spreadsheets, not worksheets.  I have two spreadsheets already linked together and the links work just fine.  The problem is when I click on a link, it opens up in a new tab. Is there a way to make it open in the same window that I'm working in?